# What are other ways to say "pair of socks"?

Tags: adjectives

Can I use the thing that's paired as an adjective to "pair"?

If yes, should sock be singular or plural?

"sock pair"? or "socks pair"?

Comment: Heh heh. How about a "brace" of socks?  https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124850/meaning-and-etymology-of-hat-trick-and-brace

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't. You can leave out *pair* -

> I'm putting my socks on.
>
> May I borrow your binoculars?

- but it has to be *a pair of X*.

Comment: That's true for _socks_, but it's not true for all X - for instance _[electron pair](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/electron-pair)_ is common in chemistry, and _[dog pair](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22dog+pair%22+sledge)_ in dog sledging. In the cases where "X pair" is acceptable, X must be singular.

Comment: @psmears - OK - I stand corrected. I think it's true of paired garments, spectacles and the like, though.

Comment: I certainly can't think of an example where that doesn't hold...

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the more general case. I asked about pair of socks - but actually I'm not interested specifically in socks, just gave them as an examlple

Comment: @psmears are there some rules when "x pair" can be applied?

Comment: @manishma - psmears' examples demonstrate *jargon* that does not follow the idiomatic standard.  Atomic scientists and sledgers (i.e. people who race dog-sleds) speak amongst themselves however they choose.

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther: Might it not also be relevant that a single dog and a single electron are perfectly natural things to exist on their own. But a single ***sock*** is pretty worthless even if you have one (and a single ***binocular*** or ***trouser*** can't exist in the first place! :)

Comment: @manishma: It's hard to give exact rules. You're definitely safer using "pair of Xs"; that's likely to be OK in most if not all cases.

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther: I don't think it's fair to dismiss those examples as "jargon": they come across as quite normal to me (native speaker, not a chemist, not a dog-sledder). And if you don't like those, how about [word pairs](https://www.simpleenglishvideos.com/31-word-pairs-for-natural-fluent-english/) or [letter pairs](https://www.morewords.com/pair), both of which seem reasonably common?

Comment: @psmears - I see your point but I consider *electron pair* jargon that you and I learned in high school/college chemistry class.  *Dog pair* is sledging jargon that we understand because we know what dog sledding is and how it works.  Ask stranger to list three *word pairs*.  My guess is that you will need to provide more info before they know what is meant by *word pair* because it's jargon.

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther: Where do you draw the line for what is "jargon" versus what is "normal idiomatic language"? For me, if we learn something out of our high school textbooks, that's almost certainly part of the language :) (And yes, a stranger might be confused if I asked them for a word pair - but they'd be equally bemused if I asked them, without further explanation, for a pair of words - or indeed a pair of socks!)

Comment: @psmears - Asking someone for a *pair of words* would be quite confusing.  It has no meaning outside the jargon - *word pair*.  Folks who didn't lean chemistry jargon in chemistry class are unfamiliar with the jargon.  Folks who did learn it are familiar with it.  Very Prima-Facie.  :)

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther: "it has no meaning outside the jargon". By that reasoning, _all_ idioms are "jargon"...